# Running OpenCL apps with bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, cuda, opencl

I have installed CUDA Toolkit 5.0 and nvidia-experimental-310 drivers. CUDA examples works fine with `optirun` but every OpenCL app fails to run with error calling `clGetPlatformIDs` function. I've tried examples from NVIDIA OpenCL SDK and also examples from PyOpenCL which I compiled from source and also using `pip`, nothing works. Why it's not working?

Answer (score 6):

I finally managed to get it work after creating `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd` file and `libnvidia-opencl.so.1` inside. I also switched back to `nvidia-current` driver before but I'm sure it still would work with experimental ones.
I found a solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/darktable/+bug/1039684).

Comment: Thank you for that, very helpful in getting my OpenCL running.